# Moving ball from ball own position Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am want to move my ball around using mouse, Currently ball following mouse position, I want to follow mouse behaving but not position.

I was try to move by velocity but i am moving my ball foreword using velocity so its behave unexpected.

```
 private void Update()
  {
    rigid.velocity = new Vector3(0f, -2f, Time.deltaTime * speed);
      if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         RaycastHit hit;
         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
          {
            Vector3 point = hit.point;

            rigid.MovePosition(new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x,Mathf.Clamp(point.x, -3, 3),5 * Time.deltaTime), transform.position.y, transform.position.z));

        }
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 1)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                rigid.MovePosition(new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(touch.position.x, -3, 3), 5 * Time.deltaTime), transform.position.y, Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, touch.position.y, 5 * Time.deltaTime)));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is for moving ball according to mouse, but i want to not follow position of mouse. I need to follow only behave like left right up and down.

Comment: I would probably approach this with an AddForce approach. Add force to the ball in the vector the mouse travelled from the previous frame to this frame.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but conceptually something like this:

```
Vector2 prevMousePos = Vector2.zero;
private float power = 10; // Change this to edit power

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector2 direction = (mousePos - prevMousePos).normalized;
        rigid.AddForce(direction * power);
        prevMousePos = mousePos;
    }
}
```

Please note that if you set Velocity every `Update()` like your code is currently doing, it will override all other physics movement. You could go around this by doing AddForce as a constant movement as well and then to make sure the object doesn't go infinitely fast, add a check for velocity and limiting it:

```
const float MAX_VELOCITY = 10;

void Update() 
{
    /* 
     * ... Input.GetMouseButton(0) ...
     */

    // Add force in the direction you today have set for rigid.velocity
    rigid.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, -2f, Time.deltaTime * speed));

    // Make sure the AddForce doesn't goes faster than MAX_VELOCITY
    if (rigid.velocity.magnitude > MAX_VELOCITY) 
    {
        rigid.velocity = rigid.velocity.normalized * MAX_VELOCITY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well there is some blocks to stop force by adding addforce every time i collides with blocks force will go down, There is many blocks back to back so add force is not fit for that condition.

Comment: Then you'll have to do it similarly but mutate the velocity instead. Should be the same thing, conceptually; check the mouse position difference between last frame and this frame and add that to current velocity vector.